# Key-Value Pairs in Redis

Tags: python, nosql, redis, key-value, key-value-store

I'm planning to use Redis, to store a list of image links associated with a set of keywords for fast retrieval.

But, I'm kinda confused on defining my keys here.

I'd like to have a set of keywords, maybe 3 or 4 as my keys. so, If I search for any of the keyword combination, I get the list of images returned.

How can I define my keys to store multiple words? I know that it's not advisable to have mutable keywords, but I *don't* want to make changes to the keys later. 
To explain further:

( 'jack', 'dorsey', 'twitter' ) : [link/to/image1.jpg,  link/to/image2.jpg,link/to/image3.jpg]

( 'jack', 'dorsey', 'square' ) : [link/to/image1.jpg,  link/to/image2.jpg, link/to/image3.jpg]

Even if I could create bigrams or just trigrams in keys, that would help.

1. Is this possible?
2. Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think its directly possible to do it that way but you could simply do

```
import redis
import json
r = redis.Redis()
r.rpush(json.dumps(("jack", "dorsey", "twitter"), image)
```

Then when you want to check something against the key or other you just use the `json.dumps` of your data structure